# Filter WinForms DataGridView by date range

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2005

I would like to filter my DataGridView by a date range which is listed below.

I have a ListBox with 2 items with start and end date. Start date on top, end date below in listbox.

[image: listbox = lbSearchByTime]

ListBox

[image: DataGridView with column named 'DATE']

DataGridView with date column named `'DATE'`

Note: all DateTime formats in my DataGridView and ListBox are `dd/MM/yyyy`, example: `05/23/2013`

```
Filter = "(DATE >= '" + lbSearchByTime.Items[0].ToString().Trim() + 
         "and DATE <= '" + lbSearchByTime.Items[1].ToString().Trim() + "')";

Filter = "(DATE >= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(lbSearchByTime.Items[0].ToString().Trim()) +
         and "DATE <= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(lbSearchByTime.Items[1].ToString().Trim()) + "')";
```

These 2 codes does not work for me. Is it wrong format or something else?
It does not have any change when perform filter by button_click.

Comment: Is `Date` the column name? look at this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2h7C-IL-FB8)

Comment: yes, it is the column name

Comment: I upvoted the question, you now have enough points to upload an image of the problem:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if (lbSearchByTime.Items.Count == 2)
        {
            DateTime start = stringToDateTime(lbSearchByTime.Items[0].ToString().Trim());
            DateTime end = stringToDateTime(lbSearchByTime.Items[1].ToString().Trim());

            Filter = "(DATE101 >= #" + start + "# and DATE101 <= #" + end + "#)";
        }
```